# AudioContext и createGain

Tags: javascript, аудио

По какой причине gain может не влиять на громкость? Вроде бы все правильно подключил.

```
    var context = new ( window.AudioContext ||
                                window.webkitAudioContext ||
                                window.mozAudioContext ||
                                window.oAudioContext ||
                                window.msAudioContext)();

            var source = context.createBufferSource();

            source.loop = true; 

/// загружаю response

             context.decodeAudioData(this.response, function(buffer) {

                source.buffer = buffer;             
                source.connect(context.destination);



                var volume = context.createGain();
                source.connect(volume);
                volume.connect(context.destination);
                volume.gain.value = 0;

              }, function () {});
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, получается, что Gain является посредником между `BufferSource` и `AudioContext`, и поэтому коннектить `source` к `context.destination` не нужно